# The easiest way to convert a PHP script into OpCode using C#?

Tags: c#, php, bytecode, opcode

What is the easiest way to convert a PHP script (.php) into OpCode/Bytecode (Operation Code) using C#? I can use DLLs if I have to.

I need this to be done for the project I am working in order to analyze PHP code easier.

Any thoughts or ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Phalanger](https://github.com/devsense/phalanger) is what you're looking for.

Comment: the link you provided is now broken, [here](https://github.com/devsense/phalanger/) is a valid one

Comment: For anyone wondering, [**Peach Pie**](https://www.peachpie.io/) now officially replaces Phalanger.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can do a literal conversion since it is interpreted on the fly. You would essentially have to dissect the PHP engine.

Each PHP engine will be different and in another example of using Phalanger, that is simply being converted to CLR -- ie: it's no longer PHP so you would really be analyzing .NET CLR.

Comment: I would think so. It depends exactly what you are analyzing.

Comment: I am trying to analyze the execution flow. For instance, I want to know what is being passed into certain functions and when.